# Estratégias para desligar instâncias vinculadas ao Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-aws, elastic-beanstalk

Estou buscando alternativas para desligar aplicativos gerenciados via Elastic Beanstalk durante algumas horas diariamente na intenção de reduzir custos com a AWS.

Minha configuração atual é:

- EB do tipo "load balancing" com auto scaling de no mínimo 1 e no máximo 2 instâncias;
- ELB do tipo "application";
- Instância RDS para a base de dados.

O EB aparentemente não dispõe dessa funcionalidade via console, o mais próximo que encontrei é a opção "Terminate", que elimina toda  configuração realizada - não é o que desejo. Diante disso busquei desligar individualmente as instâncias. O RDS é ok mas a instância EC2 não funciona em razão do autoscaling (o beanstalk a elimina e cria um nova). Em relação ao Load balancer também não encontrei nada que o desligasse.

Pesquisando possíveis soluções encontrei os seguintes links:

- https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/1373c4c
- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=240756&tstart=0
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-suspend-resume-processes.html

Pensei em **suspender a ação de "ReplaceUnhealthy" do autoscaling** pra desabilitar o encerramento de instâncias não saudáveis e a criação de novas instâncias para substituí-las, paralelamente configurar o desligamento da instância EC2 e do RDS nos horários desejados. Quanto ao ELB não encontrei alternativa para o desligamento temporário.

Peço ajuda para analisar a **viabilidade dessa estratégia e possíveis consequências** indesejadas e/ou **compartilhamento de alguma alternativa para realizar o desligamentos das instâncias** na configuração atual.

Grato.